# Function pointer as non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently porting GTK+ to a dynamic language, one of the challenge is to convert GTK+ functions to language bindings. I attempt to use C++ templates to simplify it.

For example, to convert 'gtk_widget_show_all' to dynamic language's 'show_all', I first define following generic function:

```
template<class Type, class GtkType, void function (GtkType*)>
static Handle<Value> SimpleMethod (const Arguments& args) {
    GtkType *obj = blablabla...;

    function (obj);

    return Undefined (); 
}
```

Then I can bind the 'gtk_widget_show_all' to 'show_all' very easily:

```
NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD (constructor_template, "show_all", (SimpleMethod<Widget, GtkWidget, gtk_widget_show_all>));
```

But when the GTK+ function becomes more complex, It would be a hell for defining every SimpleMethod for every type of GTK+ function, like this:

```
template<class Type, class GtkType, void function (GtkType*, const char *)>
static Handle<Value> SimpleMethod (const Arguments& args) {
    ...
}

template<class Type, class GtkType, void function (GtkType*, int)>
static Handle<Value> SimpleMethod (const Arguments& args) {
    ...
}

template<class Type, class GtkType, int function (GtkType*)>
static Handle<Value> SimpleMethod (const Arguments& args) {
    ...
}

template<class Type, class GtkType, void function (GtkType*, const char *, const char *)>
static Handle<Value> SimpleMethod (const Arguments& args) {
    ...
}
```

It will become rather disgusting. Is there a good way to simplify those functions to one function?

Comment: If you are using C++ why not use existing C++ wrapper for GTK+ [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/)?

Comment: @another.anon.coward GTK+ is designed to be bound to other languages, while gtkmm adds many C++ features, they are useless when porting to dynamic languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a number of overloads, based on the number of arguments, like this:

```
template<class Type, class GtkType, class ReturnType, ReturnType function ()>
static Handle<Value> SimpleMethod (const Arguments& args) {
    ...
}

template<class Type, class GtkType, class ReturnType, class Arg0, ReturnType function( Arg0 )>
static Handle<Value> SimpleMethod (const Arguments& args) {
    ...
}

...and so on...
```

Boost.Preprocessor would help you generate the overloads. C++11 variadic template arguments should make this much easier.

Comment: Your idea is good, but is it possible to use C++11 variadic template arguments to generate arbitrary long function calls, like `function (Arg0, Arg1, ...)`?

Comment: @fool: I believe it is, perhaps with some extra template magic around, but my compiler does not yet support them so I wouldn't know for sure.